# How do I return a value from database to template?

Tags: html, django, sqlite

I have a database that uses formset to help store data. How do I get the ‘value’ of the numbers of data in the template? For example, I got a queryset of `{[Item 1],[ Item 2]}`. How do I get the value of 2 in the template to tell me there's 2 items? I want to use this value to control the amount of stuff I can clone with a click of the button. I'm using Django for the web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just ask |length of the queryset, like:

```
{{ queryset|length }}
```

will be returning the number of element

Comment: I managed to get the value but if i want to store this value in my script. How should i do that?

Comment: You must give this length as a value to an input

Comment: Got it. Thanks !